# 500 oops bad bool value in config file for anonymous_enable

Tags: centos, ftp, vsftpd

I'm start getting this message when i'm trying to run `vsftpd`

```
500 oops bad bool value in config file for anonymous_enable
```

Relevant part from the `vsftpd.conf` file:

```
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Beware - allowed by default if you comment this out).
anonymous_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
```

When i'm commenting the `anonymous_enable=YES`, then i got the same error on the following line `local_enable=YES`

```
500 oops bad bool value in config file for local_enable
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be caused by having [trailing space](http://www.andreaswacker.com/blog/2009/01/31/vsftpd-500-oops-error/) at the end of the line. Check that there is no whitespace after "YES". If that isn't the case check that you don't have Windows CRLF line endings.

The following `sed` command will remove any trailing space and CR characters from the specified file:

```
sed -i 's,\r,,;s, *$,,' /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Comment: No spaces, how can I check the windows line ending?

Comment: @udidu I've added a command to removing trailing space and CR characters from files.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: I'm using Windows.
I've transfered vsftpd.conf file over pscp with parameters then got that error.
as a solution, I've retransfered file as empty and edit the file and paste parameters via nano and it works.